# Let $n\in\mathbb N$ be given. Find an integer $m$, and polynomials $f,g,h$ such that $f^2+g^2+h^2=135m^2n^2-30m^2n-5m^2$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $n$ be a given positive integer. Find an integer $m$, and polynomials $f,g,h$ in $n$, such that

$f^2+g^2+h^2=135m^2n^2-30m^2n-5m^2$

or prove that it is impossible.

I've tried this problem for ages but I still can't get anywhere. My idea was to try expressing $135m^2$ as a sum of three squares. Any help?

Comment: OK, there is some confusion here as shown by the 2 answers. Are we trying to get equal polynomials in $n$, or solve for a particular value of $n$?

Answer (score 0):

Impossible - you can't get a negative constant (here, $-5m^2$) out of summing squared polynomials (with real coefficients).

However you did sucker me into checking what values of $m$ might allow $135m^2$ to be decomposed into three squares...

Comment: @GEdgar clarified that it's the constant I'm talking about. No issue with the coefficient of $n$ of course.

Comment: Sorry I cannot comment but what @Joffan says is wrong I believe. Just factor $5m^2$ from the left side and what remains is $27n^2-6n-1$ which is definitely positive since $n$ is a positive integer and $5m^2$ is also positive.

Comment: Differing interpretation, let's see... meanwhile you lay bare that the right-hand side can be factored into $5m^2(3n-1)(9n+1)$, which might yet be useful...